# Docker containers in a custom bridge network and a dnsmasq service on host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns, docker-network, dnsmasq

TL;DR: How do I make containers to use dnsmasq running on the host machine as a DNS?

Details of what I tried and where I am rn are below.

In my `docker-compose.yml` I set up a custom network:

```
networks:
  mycustomnet:
    driver: bridge
```

and all containers are on it:

```
services:
  mycontainer:
    networks:
      - mycustomnet
```

As per [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) and [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52242360/664178) here on SO, in a configuration like this, docker will setup `/etc/resolv.conf` in the container to point to `127.0.0.11`, which will then forward DNS requests to whatever the host DNS resolver is set to. That's my understanding, and indeed it seems to do set that correctly:

```
root@717f2c8ce87e:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

My host is configured with a dnsmasq service that resolves our internal TLDs (say, `.example`) against a cloud provider (DO) DNS server, and everything else is resolved against Google and Cloudflare DNS. From `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
server=/example/173.245.58.51
server=/example/173.245.59.41
server=/example/198.41.222.173
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
server=1.1.1.1
server=1.0.0.1
```

On my host I can do `nslookup test.example` and it is getting correctly resolved:

```
-> # nslookup test.example
Server:         ::1
Address:        ::1#53

Name:   test.example
Address: 10.104.0.4
```

But if I do the same in the container, it doesn't resolve hostnames with internal TLDs:

```
-> # docker exec -it mycontainer_1 bash
root@717f2c8ce87e:/# nslookup test.example
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

** server can't find test.example: NXDOMAIN
```

But it does resolve addresses such as `google.com` or `github.com`:

```
root@717f2c8ce87e:/# nslookup google.com
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.194.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.194.102
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.194.101
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.194.139
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.194.113
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.194.138
Name:   google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4003:c04::8b
Name:   google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4003:c04::71
Name:   google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4003:c04::64
Name:   google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4003:c04::66
```

This is quite confusing because I don't quite understand what DNS server it *is* using. Clearly, not the host machine's dnsmasq, or otherwise it should have resolved the `.example` domains too – I guess?

What am I missing? How do I resolve `.example` domains from within the container? And how can I check *which* DNS server my containers currently use?

Comment: Did you find a resolution? I am running into the exact same issue.

Comment: @KristiKozak no, I did not. I ended up running a DNS server on a separate small instance and using the `dns:` setting in my compose files to point there.